# Is there an option to write node add-on in python?

Tags: python, node.js, node-gyp

I want to have node bindings for a library that already has nice python bindings.  I wonder if I can utilize those.  If I add a python file in binding.gyp, node-gyp doesn't complain, but if I want to use it later on, it says the module did not self-register.  Of course it did not because I don't know what to put in that file.  But I cannot find any documentation on that, so I suspect it just works because no file gets compiled an the python script provided is not used at all.  Is there an option to write node add-on in python?

I looked up some bridges, but it looks like they are stateless. What I need is to keep some objects around (connection-related). Also having the option of emitting events would be nice.

Comment: There's a couple of node / python bridge modules on npm, did you try those?

Comment: I have found only one and it was only running single python commands. I need to keep some objects aroud, so I need more than that. I'll update the question.